# How to multiply UIStepper value to Textfield value ios?

Tags: ios, math, uitextfield, uistepper

How to multiply UIStepper value (product quantity) to textfield value (product price) and get total sum in uilabel.text?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UIStepper` has a `.value` property that you can use:

```
double sumTotal = stepper.value * [[textField text] doubleValue];
```